# how to create object inside function of value in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I create and access object inside anonymous function of value?

```
var obj1 = {key1: "val1", key2: {a: "this is a val"} };
```

in obj1 I know I can access it as `console.log(obj1.key2.a);`

Is it possible to do it this way

```
var obj2 = {key1: "val1", key2: function(){   {a: "this is a val"}   }};
```

If it is then how I will access the a: val;

Comment: `var obj2 = {key1: "val1", key2: function(){   return {a: "this is a val"}   }};` ... then call the function and get property frm returned object `console.log(obj2.key2().a);`

Comment: but it is returning the whole object, how to get it's key only?

Comment: I mean I want to get "this is a val"

Comment: Did you try Pranav's code? It outputs "this is a val".

Comment: `obj2.key2().a` ===> `"this is a val"`

Comment: okey yes it is printing that value

Comment: thanks both of you pranav and paulpro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the object from the function in order to access it. After adding `return` statement you can get the object by calling the function then get the property `a`.

```js
var obj2 = {
  key1: "val1",
  key2: function() {
    return {
      a: "this is a val"
    }
  }
};

console.log(obj2.key2().a)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a bit more flexibility (and to be able to access your value the way you originally proposed), you can have key2 be a getter function instead of a regular key pointing to a function:

```js
var obj2 = {
  key1: "val1",
  get key2 () {
    return {
      a: "this is a val"
    }
  }
};

console.log(obj2.key2.a)
```